# Which channel to extract - ImageJ

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I have an image, and I'm trying to extract a certain channel depending on how red, blue or green the image is.

For example, if my image is predominately red, I want to extract the red channel. I already have the code which will extract the channels for me:

```
private ImageProcessor getRedChannel(ImageProcessor ip) {
    RGBStackSplitterSean splitter=new RGBStackSplitterSean();
    splitter.split(new ImagePlus("tempImage",ip));
    ImagePlus red=new ImagePlus("tempImage",splitter.red);
    return red.getProcessor();
}
```

How do I go about determining which channel is the strongest?

Thanks!

#### Edit:

I ended up doing as @mmgp mentioned. Sum up all intensities for each channel and pick the largest using:

```
private int getSumPixels(ImageProcessor ip){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ip.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int k=0; k<ip.getHeight(); k++){
                sum = sum + ip.getPixel(i, k);
            }
        }
        return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum all the intensities per channel and pick the one with the largest sum.

Comment: You might want to divide each intensity by the maximum intensity (255 most likely) to not have a chance of overflowing.